# jQuery change css of ul nodes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change the color of `li` elements if text in that `li` element is "OFF".

HTML structure:

```
-> OL
   -> UL
      -> UL
         -> LI - if LI text is "OFF" its color should be red.
   -> UL
     -> UL
        -> LI
```

I made something like that but not work:

```js
$("#content").children().each(function () {
  $(this).children().each(function () {
    if (this.text == "OFF")
      $(this).css({ 'color': 'red' });
  })
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by text is off? Could you supply your HTML?

Comment: @Aaron If text content is "OFF".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You need to do this way:

```
$("#content").find("li").each(function () {
  if ($(this).text().trim() == "OFF")
    $(this).css({ 'color': 'red' });
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("#content").find("li").each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().trim() == "OFF")
      $(this).css({ 'color': 'red' });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<ol id="content">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>OFF</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>ON</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```